# nginx autostart fails systemd

Tags: nginx, systemd

I compiled nginx from source and installed it. Also I made the systemd service for nginx (https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/systemd/). But it won't start automatically in boot. Instead I need to manually initialize it.

The systemctl's log

```
● nginx.service - The NGINX HTTP and reverse proxy server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
```

Could someone please explain how to start the service on boot

Comment: Based on the information in your question? No, we're not psychics. What does your logs say?

Comment: the service is disabled - it says so right there ... `sudo systemctl enable nginx` and amazingly it will work

Comment: Hi now it starts on boot. Thanks @JaromandaX. I was too reckless. Never mind.